# Java semi-shared properties

Tags: java

Is there a way to have a shared property between multiple (but not all) instances of a class, such as 2 nodes which have a shared length between them? How could I implement something like this or would I have to go about it in a different way?

Comment: I want to create a map of nodes which have lengths between them to represent a "Maze" ie a square grid with walls & paths, each node would represent a junction

Comment: One possibility is to model not only the nodes, but also the edges between those nodes. Those can then have a length. Anyway, you might want to check out some resources on [graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28abstract_data_type%29).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing Graph - Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33678937/implementing-graph-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing. It's even built-in to the language.

```
Length l = new Length();
Node n1 = new Node(l);
Node n2 = new Node(l);
```

Those two nodes now share the length object, and no other nodes share it.

Comment: Would I need to define Length as static too?

Comment: Why on earth would you do that? You should probably learn how to (not) use `static` before you start designing your maze. It's easier to do things when you understand the basics of the language.

Comment: That's true but the reason I'm doing this is to try to learn how to use the language, thanks for being so tolerant of my ignorance though. I'll try to learn in a less disruptive way.

Comment: That's the wrong way to learn (in my opinion and based on the people I've seen telling they "learn by doing"). You don't learn to walk by going to a marathon, asking other people if you should be moving your legs at the same time or one at a time. Tutorials are made to teach you the basics, then you can move on to more advanced things when you have some idea about what you're doing.